# help in installing new stackable washer-dryer

Tags: dryer, washer

My old Asko "stackable" set has lived is life and is on life support so I need to replace it am looking to install this package - [GE - 2.4 Cu. Ft. Front Load Washer and 4.1 Cu. Ft. 13-Cycle Electric Dryer - White](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/combo/washer-dryer-bundles/70596da5-6cfe-428b-b0f2-ef0ecd1cf539#questionsAndAnswersAccordion_6313656)

Now the Asko plugged into the wall with this NEMA 14-30 connector

[image: pics of NEMA 14-30 socket and plug] [(originals)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mq8L.jpg)

*When I install the GE stackable do I hook up the 4 prong plug on the rear of the dryer?*

[image: pic of wiring instructions for 3 or 4 wire cable]
[(original)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBcjH.jpg)

*If I do use the 4 prong plug, which one of these do I order?*

[image: pic of chart of cord model numbers]
[(original)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTPgd.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

That's a standard NEMA 14-30 receptacle and 4-prong plug.  You need 4 prongs/wires, not 3, because neutral needs to be separate from safety ground, like it is for every other appliance in your house.

3-prong connections date back to before grounding (so, like, before 1960) and a temporary exception granted to dryers and ranges that they didn't need to come into modern (1960s) codes.  The logic is these connections are rarely disturbed, so a neutral contact failure is unlikely, even though this would guarantee that the chassis of the machine is electrified.  Anyway, you don't want that.

I'll be the first cheerleader for using parts of known quality from a vetted source; however, LOL, dryer cords are commodities and you can use any sold at a retail store. There's a nasty virus going around so I'd order delivery or "curbside pickup" from Home Depot or Lowes.

Whenever you're dealing with a stackable, watch your plugs and sockets. Some apartment and condo developments use *very particular* models of washer-dryer that let them reduce the number of circuits and utilities they must install in each laundry room.  Strategies include:

- Electric to eliminate a gas line, obviously.
- Specifying a heat pump (condensing) dryer to eliminate dryer vent
- Specifying stackable washer-dryer pair that are custom-matched, so the washer takes power from the dryer's NEMA 14-30 plug, eliminating need for a 120V circuit in the space

The last two can "bite" people in such developments, who presume they can replace a washer-dryer stackable with "any old thing".  Only to find there is no dryer vent, or no 120V power.

Comment: Every indication is that virus is fading rapidly and even the most paranoid nations are rolling back their requirements. Just go on into store unless you're in an especially vulnerable medical state.

Comment: @FreeMan The social gestalt feels that way, yes.  However I never trust that, I always look at the hard numbers.  [Wow, just wow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics_of_the_COVID-19_pandemic_in_the_United_States).  Sorta like declaring the Civil War "over" because Antietam was a month ago.  I've said it before, people have a really hard time assessing safety accurately.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 4 prong receptacle so need to use a 4 prong plug.

Any one of the bottom three will work, just depends on the length you want, how far is the dryer to the receptacle.

Comment: what about just getting a new dryer will this dryer https://www.ebay.com/itm/274560094547?hash=item3fed0e9153:g:uvIAAOSwBlhfoWli hookup to my ASKO W6022? Thank You I can use a short cord its all close

Comment: Would ask that question to the seller.  They should know and answer quite soon.  They do sell that make and know which model/s will fit properly.

Comment: I don't think, @MatthewPipep, it matters what dryer you get, they'll be wired for a 4-wire setup as that's modern (since the 1960s) code, with the ability to adapt to the positively ancient (pre-1960s) wiring if necessary. Unless you get a pair that are designed to be connected together, but then the washer will plug into the dryer (as noted in [Harper's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/245099/34147).